# Finding implicit coercion to boolean in source code

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-analysis

How can I find all implicit conversions to boolean in source code? This includes conditional statements like `if x`, loops like `while x`, operators like `x or y`, etc.; but not `if x == 0` or `if len(x) == 0`, etc. I don't mind using a static analyzer, or IDE, or a regular expression, or a python library designed for this purpose. Of course there will be some false positives, when `x` is actually boolean; that's fine.

Use case: I found bugs caused by coercion to boolean. For example, a variable `x` was supposed to be an integer or `None` and was incorrectly tested with `if not x` implying `if x is None`. I want to make all boolean conversions explicit (e.g., replacing `if not x` with `if x is None` or `if x == 0`, etc.). Of course, it would have to be done manually, but at least identifying the locations where implicit conversion occurs would be helpful.

Comment: You know that `x or y` is kind of a hybrid - the inputs are *evaluated* as boolean, but the *output* of the full expression will be one of the inputs (not boolean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there's a typing library that does precisely this. It works for both python 2 and python 3.

See [mypy](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), use command `--strict-boolean`.

I move the accepted answer to this one, even though @AustinHastings has a very useful answer about how one could do it using `ast`, because I want people to be aware of `mypy` - it's a great tool (not likely to be abandoned any time soon, with 100+ contributors, including Guido).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you take a look at the standard `ast` module. Here is some trivial code:

```
import ast
source = '''
x=1
if not x:
    print('not x')
'''

tree = ast.parse(source)
print(ast.dump(tree))
```

And here is the output:

> ```
> $ python test.py
> Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='x', ctx=Store())], value=Num(n=1)), If(test=UnaryOp(op=Not(), operand=Name(id='x', ctx=Load())), body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print', ctx=Load()), args=[Str(s='not x')], keywords=[]))], orelse=[])])
> ```

Eli Bendersky has written an [article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/11/28/python-internals-working-with-python-asts/) on working with AST's, and he includes some sample code for *visiting* the nodes of an AST. You would want to do a visit where you looked for particular constructions. In the example above, you'd be looking for (sub)expressions beneath an `If` node where an operand was either directly treated as a boolean, or treated as the sole operand to a `Not()` node.

Finding every possible case could be quite complex. But I think you can easily find the "simple" cases (if x, if not x, if x or y) with a page or two of code.

**EDIT:** Here's some code that (I think) does what you want.

```
import ast
source = '''#Line 1
x=1
y=2

if not x:
    print('not x')

if y is None:
    print('y is none')


while y or not x or (x < 1 and not y and x < 10):
    print('x < 10')
    x += 1

'''

tree = ast.parse(source)

class FindNameAsBoolean(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, lines):
        self.source_lines = lines

    def report_find(self, kind, locn, size=3):
        print("\nFound %s at %s" % (kind, locn))
        print(self.source_lines[locn[0]-1])
        print(' ' * locn[1], '^' * size, sep='')

    def visit_UnaryOp(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.op, ast.Not) and isinstance(node.operand, ast.Name):
            self.report_find('NOT-NAME', (node.lineno, node.col_offset), size=4 + len(node.operand.id))
        self.generic_visit(node)

    def visit_BoolOp(self, node):
        opname = type(node.op).__name__.upper()
        for kid in node.values:
            if isinstance(kid, ast.Name):
                self.report_find('%s-NAME' % opname, (node.lineno, node.col_offset), size=len(kid.id))

        self.generic_visit(node)

class FindTests(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, lines):
        self.source_lines = lines

    def _fnab(self, node):
        cond = node.test
        FindNameAsBoolean(self.source_lines).visit(cond)

    def visit_If(self, node):
        self._fnab(node)
        self.generic_visit(node)

    def visit_While(self, node):
        self._fnab(node)
        self.generic_visit(node)

FindTests(source.splitlines()).visit(tree)
```

And here's the output:

> ```
> $ python test.py
>
> Found NOT-NAME at (5, 3)
> if not x:
>    ^^^^^
>
> Found OR-NAME at (12, 6)
> while y or not x or (x < 1 and not y and x < 10):
>       ^
>
> Found NOT-NAME at (12, 11)
> while y or not x or (x < 1 and not y and x < 10):
>            ^^^^^
>
> Found NOT-NAME at (12, 31)
> while y or not x or (x < 1 and not y and x < 10):
>                                ^^^^^
> ```

Comment: As a complement, you should read the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) and identify the exact statements you want to isolate. What you want is probably around `test`.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea was to decorate the built-in `bool` function, but for some reason, this did not work with Python 3.4.

Therefore, I propose a solution, when the full set of the potentially used classes is known: basically decorate the `__bool__` method of every class.

```
def bool_highlighter(f):
    def _f(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Coercion to boolean")
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return _f

for c in classes:
    try:
        c.__bool__ = bool_highlighter(c.__bool__)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

I just assumed that `classes` was an iterable containing the targeted classes. You can probably populate it dynamically.

If you execute this code at the startup, every boolean coercion will print `"Coercion to boolean"`.

Just a short test:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, v):
...         self.v = v
...
...     def __bool__(self):
...         return self.v == 12
...
>>> foo = Foo(15)
>>> if not foo:
...     print("hello")
...
Coercion to boolean
hello
```

Comment: I was hoping to do that statically, not dynamically -- primarily because there's no way of ensuring that every single coercion will be on an execution path during testing. In addition, there's no way to decorate `__bool__` of built-in types, which is where most of the implicit conversions happen.

Comment: @max I understand. Well, I'll let my answer here because it might be useful, but surely this does not solve your problem...